# How to load remote content in server for my Firefox OS app - In Web and FxOS device

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications, xmlhttprequest, firefox-os

I haven't found this trouble in the forum so I write this.

I'm having a problem with FirefoxOS app in my FirefoxOS device (Geeksphone Developer Preview) when I take remote content from the server.

I'm doing calls to PHP file in server by AJAX since my JS files, and it prints the contentResult in my HTML files. It's done correctly.

This is javascript file content

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    'use strict';
    var translate = navigator.mozL10n.get;
    navigator.mozL10n.once(start);
    function start() {
        var message = document.getElementById('message');
        message.textContent = translate('message');
        show_content();
    }
    document.getElementById("btn_1").addEventListener("click",function(){
        console.log("hola mundo");
        alert("hola mundo");
    });

    document.getElementById("btn_2").addEventListener("click",function(){
        console.log("adios mundo");
        alert("adios mundo");
    });

    function show_content(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = server_path + "ejemplo.php";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txt_server").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

});

function aviso(){
    console.log("clicked");
    alert("clicked");
}
```

This is HTML file content

```
<html>
      <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Example app</title>
            <meta name="description" content="A privileged app stub">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" defer></script>
            <link rel="prefetch" type="application/l10n" href="data/locales.ini" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/l10n.js" defer></script>
        </head>
      <body>
            <section>
                <h1 data-l10n-id="app_title">My example app</h1>
                <p data-l10n-id="app_description">With this example, I want to show a button loaded in HTML and then load content from server by XMLHttpRequest. Two buttons will have click function developed, with alert and console message.</p>
                <p id="message"></p>
                <button class="wide" data-l10n-id="btn_1" id="btn_1">Click me 1</button>
                <button class="wide" data-l10n-id="btn_2" id="btn_2" hidden></button>
                <p><span id="txt_server"></span></p>
            </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is PHP file content

```
<?php
    //to solve CORS advice
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");    

    echo "<button class=\"wide\" data-l10n-id=\"btn_2\" id=\"btn_2\">Click me 2</button><br/>";
    echo "<a onclick=\"aviso();\" class=\"wide\">Click me 3</a>";

?>
```

So, the problem is:

1. The button which is created dinamicaly when I call to PHP file hasn't a clickable function, in web and in FxOS app neither.
2. The "a" element which is also created in the call to PHP file, in
   web it has clickable function [it shows an alert and log] but in app
   installed in FxOS device it doesnt do anything.

In this [link](https://galan.ehu.es/imagonbar88/DAS/Pruebas/Example/example_webapp/index.html) you could test what I'm trying to explain you. 
If you want to see the code, there is a zip file. [zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgbxe582pc1xz3v/example_webapp.rar?dl=0)

Thanks for your time. Ask me if you don't understand something.

Comment: In your JavaScript, what is `server_path` defined as?  If you're installing the app as a packaged app (type: web, or type: privileged, in the manifest), then the domain of the app is in the format app://<uuid>, and therefor is subject to the same origin policy.  Indeed, when I run your example, I see: ReferenceError: server_path is not defined.  Also, does the network tab in the Simulator dev tools provide any insights? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE#Running_and_debugging_apps and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot telling that 'server_path' is the url of my server, I deleted this when I uploaded the code. 

I use Mozilla WebIDE and console doesn't show me any error by web and by fxos app. Only, when the webpage loads in web, appears warning message about the server certificate isn't secure.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to reproduce locally, and also am not seeing CORS work correctly.  I will file a bug in the mean time and follow up.  One thing you could do in the meantime is switch to using systemXHR from the client side, rather than CORS on the server side.  See: http://soledadpenades.com/2014/03/05/failproof-ajax-requests-in-firefox-os/

Comment: Ah, figured it out, will answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CSP violation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP)  You can't use onclick.

Comment: Thanks @DougReeder, your comment helps me a lot.

The problems with this example was the `"type":"certified"` line in manifest.webapp file, because this type of apps needs comply the CSP Restrictions. I have delete it and it runs perfectly.

At now, my problem is that I want create a certified (to use RadioFM) FxOS App where load remote content... If you know how I could solve it, advice me please.

Comment: @imagonbar, it's advisable to ask a seperate question in another SO post.  To answer your question, while you can play with certified apps, you cannot distribute them as they are not yet allowed in Firefox Marketplace.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps#Internal_apps

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, from the [CORS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-agent-security) Section 7.3:

- https is not allowed because of certificate errors

Where using a self signed cert is considered a certificate error.  Try using [systemXHR client side](http://soledadpenades.com/2014/03/05/failproof-ajax-requests-in-firefox-os/) rather than CORS server side.